# install torch-cluster==1.5.4 and torch-scatter==2.0.4 and torch-sparse==0.6.1 and torch-spline-conv==1.2.0 ERROR

Tags: pytorch

I have a problem. For example, when installing torch-cluster1.5.4, I encountered the following error while installing Torch1.4. Please help me. Thank you.

'''   Rolling back uninstall of torch-cluster

Failed building wheel for torch-cluster
Command ""C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\oshida\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3ik1w364\torch-cluster\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\oshida\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-d061wjr6\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\oshida\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3ik1w364\torch-cluster
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 22.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.'''

Comment: I use Python3.6.8 and cuda10.1

Comment: ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached